# make a script write on every div.class based on the div's defined variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a `<script>` which can generates blog posts, and want to add it on separated `<div>` with different styles by a `shortcode`.

example: `label,style-2`

i managed to make the `<script>` generate the options as `variables` from the `shortcode` and output it into posts and everything.. which you can preview here : [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sa_saru98/esuaLryn/)

but i have one big problem, which i don't like to add the `<script>` on every `<div>`..

this is the code i want

```
<div id='main'>
<div class='col'>

<div class="widget HTML" data-version="1" id="HTML14">
<h2 class="title">Example 1</h2>
<div class="widget-content">
label,style-1
</div>
</div>

<div class="widget HTML" data-version="1" id="HTML15">
<h2 class="title">Example 2</h2>
<div class="widget-content">
label,style-2
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
//script here
</script>
```

i tried several times and searched but i couldn't make a code that can output the results in every div i choose based on the `<div>` `shortcodes`.

this is the json xml file i get the posts from [JSON File](https://mate-theme.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/label?published&alt=json-in-script&callback=mbtlist)

Comment: I understand that currently your have a script block to write you dynamic HTML in every 'blog post' or `div` and you want to make the script universal and iterate over each and every 'widget html' one time.  Is this correct?

Comment: yes thats it @Steve0

Comment: A lot here seem to depend upon `mbtlist(json)` - what does that json look like?  Can you post that to your question?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss i did